# Extract last item from JSON in Cell

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a a column called `submission_date` with json cells that looks like this:

```
{"submitted":["January 24, 2019","January 25, 2019","January 30,
2019","February 27, 2019"],"submission_canceled":["January 24, 
2019","January 25, 2019"],"returned":"February 19, 2019"}
```

or like this:

```
{"submitted":["February 27, 2019","March 5, 2019"],"submission_canceled":"March 5, 2019"}
```

I can easily get the first result from the "submission_canceled" field by doing:

```
json_extract(submission_date, "$.submission_canceled[0]")
```

I would think if I wanted to last value I would do:

```
json_extract(submission_date, "$.submission_canceled[-1]")
```

But that is just giving me back a null. As you can see, sometimes the `submission_canceled` field will have multiple dates in a list and other times it will just have a single date, not in a list. I'd like to get the single item or the last item in the list from the `submission_canceled` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '{"submitted":["January 24, 2019","January 25, 2019","January 30, 2019","February 27, 2019"],"submission_canceled":["January 24,  2019","January 25, 2019"],"returned":"February 19, 2019"}' submission_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '{"submitted":["February 27, 2019","March 5, 2019"],"submission_canceled":"March 5, 2019"}'
)
SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE(ARRAY_REVERSE(SPLIT(JSON_EXTRACT(submission_date, '$.submission_canceled'), '","'))[OFFSET(0)], r'"|\[|\]', '') last_submission_canceled
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row id  last_submission_canceled     
1   1   January 25, 2019     
2   2   March 5, 2019
```

> Update - below is "lighter" version

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '{"submitted":["January 24, 2019","January 25, 2019","January 30, 2019","February 27, 2019"],"submission_canceled":["January 24,  2019","January 25, 2019"],"returned":"February 19, 2019"}' submission_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '{"submitted":["February 27, 2019","March 5, 2019"],"submission_canceled":"March 5, 2019"}'
)
SELECT id, REGEXP_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(submission_date, '$.submission_canceled'), r'"([^"]*)"\]?$') last_submission_canceled
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with obviously same result

```
Row id  last_submission_canceled     
1   1   January 25, 2019     
2   2   March 5, 2019
```

Comment: Sure. But unfortunately parsing json is limited in BigQuery so another option is to use js udf to mimic regular jpath functionality- I have number of answers here on SO with such examples

Comment: @ndevito1 - thank you for "forcing" me to revisit one more time my answer - see update - hope it is visibly simpler now :o)

Comment: @ndevito1 - did you have chance to try?

Comment: Yes, was able to easily implement that! Many thanks!